# Como formatar coluna tipo Moeda de um WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Como formatar a coluna ***Valor*** do WebGrid ?
Exemplo de ***3000,000*** para ***3.000,00*** ?

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid",
    headerStyle: "header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    selectedRowStyle: "select",
    footerStyle: "footer",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("", format: @<text><div style="float:left; width:100%"><div style="float:left; width:75%"><strong>Fornecedor:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.NomeFantasia</div><div style="float:left; width:25%">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Data Venc.:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.DtVencimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") </div></div><br /><div style="float:left; width:75%">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Valor Doc.:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.ValorDocumento</div><div style="float:left; width:25%">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Situação:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.NmTipoSituacao</div><br /><div style="float:left; width:100%">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Descrição:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.DsMovimento</div></text>)

    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção seria você substituir esse código:

```
<strong>Valor Doc.:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.ValorDocumento
```

Por esse código:

```
<strong>Valor Doc.:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;@string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:c}", @item.ValorDocumento)
```